# Traefik Docker Swarm Unifi setup does is not reachable from domain

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I have been trying to setup a Docker Swarm setup with Traefik:v2.x for some time and searched wide and broad on Google, but I still cannot connect to my reverse proxy from my outside domain.

My setup is as following:

Hardware (from outer to inner):

```
Technicolor MediaAccess TG799vac Xtream (modem)
 |
Unifi Security Gateway (Unifi Controller is a Raspberry Pi)
 |
x86_64 server where my (currently) single docker swarm node is running
```

Both domain and wildcard domain is pointing at my system and if I am running a single container with port 80 exposed it is working from the domain. As soon as I set it up for Traefik I can't reach my containers from outside, but my test container can be reach with curl commands from inside my network. Even if I curl the USG.

On the server I have installed Docker + Docker Swarm and running the following 2 stacks:

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.3.4
    command:
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik-public"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

and

```
version: '3'
services:
  helloworld:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.helloworld.rule=Host(`test.mydomain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.helloworld.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.services.helloworld.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

Comment: Move to kubernetes. Swarm is deprecated anyway.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to stick with Swarm.

Comment: Your choice, but learning a dead tech is a waste of your time and you're unlikely to find any help when it goes wrong (like your current question). Kubernetes implementations like K3D come with Traefik pre-deployed and using it is really easy and there's lots of help when it goes wrong. It's also more secure, having received a lot more recent updates than swarm which is out of support at the end of the year for commercial customers and already out of support for open-source, afaik.

Answer (score -1):

I little update, it is possible to access a regular container with port 80 exposed on my domain, but as soon as I spin the container up with Docker Swarm, it is no longer exposed to the internet.

The network is created as follow, which I also used for a regular container:

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable test
```

and the yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - test-swarm-network

networks:
  test:
    external: true
```

So the above does not work but the following is visible on my domain from the outside:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```